# Highlight clickable images when touching the layout

Tags: android

I have a grid view with some clickable images. When I touch the layout is there a way to highlight only the clickable images.

Answer (score 0):

You can leave a margin around the images in the gridview and then when the layout is touched you can set a different background color for those clickable images.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be an easier way. i will try it and see

Answer (score 0):

you need to creat two image one for Normal mode(`button`) and second for selected mode(`button_selected`)..

after then create one xml like as selectable.xml and put it in drawable folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/button_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/button" />
</selector>
```

after then apply this xml in background of your imageview

like as

```
android:background="@drawable/selectable"
```

Comment: Thank you. I was looking for a solution where in i dont have to keep different images for different states. thanks a lot